# What is the Sabai Directory Cron Job?

Tags: wordpress

What is the cron job for the Sabai Directory plugin? The manual is

https://domainname.com/wp-admin/options-general.php?page=sabai/settings&q=%2Fcron

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: in the backend (dashboard) for Wordpress, under settings, under Sabai which is a directory plugin, there is a button that reads 'Run Cron' which when pressed sends the expiration email(s). It is the only way in which the expiration email is sent. For some reason even with disable cron = false in config.sys, automation of the expiration email is not sent. The directory plugin comes from https://codecanyon.net/item/sabai-directory-plugin-for-wordpress/4505485